# What kind of search does ID3 perform?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

What kind of search does ID3 perform?

Comment: You might want to tell everyone as stupid as me what exactly ID3 is. Precise answers require precise questions.

Comment: this what you're talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm ?

Answer (score 1):

As ID3 iteratively builds a decision tree, I would that in each iteration it searches for the next attribute to split the examples on. The search space is the remaining attributes, and the search heuristic is maximal information gain. Wikipedia's [Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_algorithm) entry describes this well.

Comment: The search space is the attributes which haven't been split on yet - so it is just an unordered list.  The question "breadth or depth first search" doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

None. ID3 doesn't perform a search.

You could loosely describe it as an in-order walk, though.